# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar mi algoritmo de búsqueda?

Tags: excel, vba, optimización, optimizar

Necesito pasar información de un archivo a otro, sin embargo, en el primer archivo utilizo 2 columnas, una para el identificador y otra para el monto que quiero pasar. El problema es que en el segundo archivo, los identificadores no se encuentran en una sola columna, sino que cada valor es una columna y necesito pasar cada monto del archivo 1 en cada columna correspondiente del archivo 2.

```
libroFuente.Activate
Sheets("BD").Select
For j26 = 1 To lastColumnTablero
Cells(4, j26).Select
If Cells(4, j26).Value = "Ppto Habilitado Cash S/." Then
    PPTO = j26

Exit For
End If
Next j26

libroFuente.Activate
Sheets("BD").Select
For j28 = 1 To lastColumnTablero
    libroFuente.Activate
    Sheets("BD").Select
    Cells(4, j28).Select
    If Cells(4, j28).Value = "Sponsor cal 1" Then
        For j27 = 5 To lLastRow
            libroFuente.Activate
            Sheets("BD").Select
            Cells(j27, j28).Select
            ToCOE = Cells(j27, j28).Value
            For j29 = 64 To 110
                libro1.Activate
                Cells(4, j29).Select
                If Cells(4, j29).Value = ToCOE Then
                    libroFuente.Activate
                    Cells(j27, PPTO).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    libro1.Activate
                    Cells(j27, j29).Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        
        Exit For
        Else
        libroFuente.Activate
        Cells(j27, PPTO).Select
        Selection.Copy
        libro1.Activate
        Cells(j27, 108).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End If
        
        
        Next j29
    
    Next j27
    
    
    End If
    Next j28


End Sub
```

Comment: Deberías añadir un ejemplo con datos para entender mejor lo que pretendes hacer

Comment: Añade algún ejemplo de cómo son tus datos porque sólo con ese código no vas a recibir mucha ayuda. Cuelga algún ejemplo para ver el contexto donde utilizas tú código.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar el pegado de celdas en columna (monto supongo en el libro fuente) transponiendo, es decir, convirtiendo la columna en una fila:

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=***True***

Con Transpose:=True, si estás copiado celdas en columna

```
1
2
3
```

al pegar, lo convierte en celdas de una misma fila:

```
1 2 3
```

También (viceversa) si es estás copiando una fila

```
1 3 5
```

al pegar con Transpose:=True, lo pega en una columna:

```
1
3
5
```

También vale para varias columnas o filas:

```
1 2
3 4    -- con transpose:=True --->  1 3 5
5 7                                 2 4 7
```